# Predict x,y coordinates by z value in point cluster

Tags: 3d, predict, point-clouds

i have point clusters in my point cloud and want to fit a line though these clusters along the highest density, to predict the x,y coordinate at a certain height. These clusters can mostly be described as "pole like objects" with noise and a slight slope.

On my search i mainly stumbled across multiple linear regression, but i got the feeling that they wont help solving this. Any ideas are much appreciated!

Example data:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.3 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.3 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.8 | 5530846.3 | 256.2 |
| 360155.8 | 5530846.3 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.8 | 5530846.3 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.8 | 5530846.3 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.3 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |
| 360155.9 | 5530846.4 | 256.2 |

**Solution**:
I am an idiot. Apparently i've made a mistake which led me to think the simplest solution would not work. But it does.

I simply use the linear regression from sklearn and use x,y coordiantes together as y and the height as x value in the regression. Works quite well in my case.

Comment: Hi. Could you please add an example point cloud in your question? Maybe with 30 points max.

Comment: @Stef Hey, thanks for the reponse! I added a table and try formating it the way stackoverflow suggests it. If you just want the csv-format, that would be no problem of course.

Comment: @Stef Sorry for comment-bombing you but i found a solution. I think i messed something up, which led me to the conclusion that the simplest way does not work. Well, it does.